# Heroku "Error: Cannot find module 'request'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

Recently my Heroku stopped working. Each time I try to run any of the scripts (including a test script I wrote), I get the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'request'
Require stack:
- /app/src/util/util.js
- /app/src/main.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/util/util.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/app/src/util/util.js', '/app/src/main.js' ]
}
```

I have done everything in the Heroku troubleshoot pages below but nothing worked.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
https://help.heroku.com/TO64O3OG/cannot-find-module-in-node-js-at-runtime

I've even tried to clone a clean copy of the repo and I was able to successfully run the script via

```
npm install
npm start
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "lol-catalyst",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "LoL Catalyst.",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/main.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "archiver": "latest",
    "aws-sdk": "latest",
    "cheerio": "latest",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "html-to-text": "latest",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "request": "latest",
    "retry": "latest"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.x",
    "npm": "6.x"
  }
}
```

Procfile:

```
worker: node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=460 --gc_interval=100 src/main.js bihourly
esports: node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=460 --gc_interval=100 src/main.js esports
test: npm start
```

I've tried `heroku run test` and get the same error.

AFAIK I've not changed much of the code if any in the past couple of month and the issue seemed to have started on it's own.

I've been researching and testing for the past hour and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Addition: I have confirmed that both the npm and node version installed on heroku and locally are exactly the same.

Addition: I have tried to add random dependencies to `util.js` non of the dependencies worked except for the standard dependencies. For instance, I changed util.js to

```
const path      = require('path')
const fs        = require('fs')
const retry     = require('retry')
const request   = require('request')
...
```

Now it complains that it can't find `retry` instead of `request` however this indicates it could find `path` and `fs`.

Addition: Looks like Heroku is not installing my dependencies. According to the logs the last successful script run was on 9/23. By checking the commit history, I did push a single commit on 9/23 however all it changed was one line in a js file. This appears to be a Heroku sided issue introduced somewhat recently.

Comment: You shouldn't use request, it has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

Comment: I understand it has been deprecated however I would like to continue to use it for the time being. Does Heroku not support using deprecated libraries? (Additional context, this project is ~3 years old so it will take a lot of time to replace request)

Comment: I think I've tracked down the issue. For some reason, Heroku is not installing my dependencies. Heroku recommends against this but checking in my node_module directory solved the issue.